# AWS Elastic beanstalk + WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

Maybe a silly question, but is it possible to use AWS WAF with Elastic beanstalk or is it already included or am I looking at this entirely wrong?

Comment: Once EB deploys resources you can view and modify them yourself. After deployment go into the WAF console and take a look. You may need to script adding WAF if it tears it down on the next deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible if your environment has an ALB. You can even configure it using .ebextensions, check out blog below.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-host-attacks/

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for answer to this question too but I think WAF is only available for [CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-working-with.html#web-acl-associating-cloudfront-distribution) and for [Application Load Balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/AWS-WAF-now-available-on-Application-Load-Balancer/).

You should also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880309/can-amazon-waf-be-used-to-protect-beanstalk-applications).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. However, you need to use an Application Load Balancer. You cannot use WAF with a single instance.